Wi-Fi Adapter Not Detected on ASUS X555LF Running Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS with Kernel 6.8.0-41-generic
System Details:

Laptop Model: ASUS X555LF
Processor: Intel Core i5-5200U × 4
RAM: 8 GB
Graphics: Intel HD Graphics 5500 (BDW GT2) & NVIDIA GeForce 930M
Storage: 1.3 TB
Wi-Fi: Wi-Fi 4 (802.11bgn) (Single band) 1*1
Operating System: Ubuntu 24.04.1 LTS (64-bit)
GNOME Version: 46
Windowing System: X11
Kernel Version: Linux 6.8.0-41-generic

Issue:
My Wi-Fi adapter is not being detected, and the system reports "No WiFi Adapter Found." This issue started after a recent system update. I’ve already tried updating the system and installing proprietary drivers via the “Additional Drivers” tool, but the issue persists. The Wi-Fi adapter is supposed to support Wi-Fi 4 (802.11bgn) (Single band) 1*1.
Steps I’ve Taken:

Updated the system using sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade.
Checked for proprietary drivers under “Software & Updates” -> “Additional Drivers.”
Reinstalled the linux-firmware package.

Logs and Outputs:

Output of lshw -C network:
*-network UNCLAIMED
  description: Network controller
  product: MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
  vendor: MEDIATEK Corp.
  physical id: 0
  bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
  version: 00
  width: 32 bits
  clock: 33MHz
  capabilities: cap_list
  configuration: latency=0
  resources: memory:a3100000-a31fffff


Output of lspci -k | grep -i network -A 3:
03:00.0 Network controller: MEDIATEK Corp. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
    Subsystem: Foxconn International, Inc. MT7630e 802.11bgn Wireless Network Adapter
    Kernel modules: mt76x0e, wl



Additional Information:

The Wi-Fi adapter was working on a previous version of Ubuntu.

Questions:

Should I try installing any specific drivers or firmware updates?
Could this be a kernel-related issue, and would downgrade to a previous kernel version help?
What additional troubleshooting steps should I take to resolve this issue?

Any help or guidance would be greatly appreciated!
Thank you!

Run the 24.04 usb use "Try Ubuntu" see if it detects the wifi and the wifi is stable.

If it works then the problem is at your end and if it doesn't then the problem is either driver or kernel.

Please edit the question to include results from terminal for sudo modprobe -v mt76x0e; sudo dmesg | grep mt76

I tried various troubleshooting methods found online, and after several restarts, the WiFi is now functioning normally.
